# Fake the default instance with a named instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way with the SQL Server (2008 or newer) to fake a connection to a named instance so that it appears to look like the default instance to applications?

I have an application that has many connection strings hard coded to a default instance, and I would like to run it on a named instance.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: If you have the code I'd just take the time to move those connection strings to config files.

Comment: Yes, I have the code.  I guess I should have specified that I want to run this as a test environment which prevents me from changing all the code without breaking production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an alias to create a common name for clients that can point to different instances:

[Create or Delete a Server Alias for Use by a Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)